# C# banker's rounding error

Tags: c#, rounding, bankers-rounding

```
double a = 18.565
return Math.Round(a,2)
```

..returns 18.57.
For every other number I tried banker's rounding worked as expected, for example Math.Round(2.565,2) returned 2.56.

Any clue why and when that happens?
Is it error or am I missing something about banker's rounding?

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting different result in Math.Round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606664/getting-different-result-in-math-round)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Matthew said, 18.565 can't be accurately represented. The actual value used is 18.565000000000001278976924368180334568023681640625 (found using [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)), which is clearly beyond half-way. Now I've a sneaking feeling that *sometimes* `Math.Round` will consider a value which is *actually* beyond the half-way point, but which is as close to the half-way point as can be accurately represented, as being exactly *at* that point. However, I haven't seen any documentation describing the situations in which that's applied, and clearly it's not happening in this case. I wouldn't want to rely on it.

Even the rounded value isn't exactly 18.57 of course. It's actually 18.57000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125.

Fundamentally, if you really, really care about representing decimal values accurately, you should be using `decimal`. That's not just in terms of `Math.Round` - it goes to every aspect of handling floating point values.

That *does* give the right value for `Math.Round`, of course:

```
decimal m = 18.565m;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(m, 2)); // Prints 18.56
```

Comment: Hm, well, this was the first thing I thought of, and checked in some online converter (http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html). Ofcourse, didn't pay much attention to the fact that only first something decimals are visible, all zeros. Eh, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

18.565 can not be exactly represented as a double.  Thus, the binary representation is slightly higher, so it rounds up.  If you use decimal:

```
decimal a = 18.565m;
return Math.Round(a,2)
```

it can be exactly represented, and you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the FP representation means it isn't actually a trailing 5; the dangers of FP!

This works fine, though:

```
        decimal a = 18.565M; // <===== decimal
        var s = Math.Round(a, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Double is a floating point value, so maybe if you write it as 18.565, it is actually in memory something like 18.56500000000000000000000000000000001, and hence it is more than the midpoint.