# Rounding to 2 decimal places, without using banker's rounding

Tags: c#, .net, .net-cf-3.5

.NET and Compact Framework by default use banker's rounding which means that
the value: 1,165 will be rounded to: 1,16.

sql server as a opposite rounds it to 1,17 as for me it is the correct behaviour.

Has anyone come across rounding topic and have a workaround for a Compact Framework?
(In .net there is an additional parameter which has an influence on the rounding behaviour)

Comment: What would you like 1.16499 to round to? Always up, so 1.160001 would be 1.17?

Comment: Would like to have: 1.16. In sql server: select Round(1.16499, 2) returns that value.

Comment: Just to explain this. 1.1649999 Would round to 1.6, and 1.65 would round to 1.7. Basic Math really, 1.5 = round up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method you can use instead of decimal.round:

```
public static decimal RoundHalfUp(this decimal d, int decimals)
{
if (decimals < 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("The decimals must be non-negative", 
        "decimals");
}

decimal multiplier = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimals);
decimal number = d * multiplier;

if (decimal.Truncate(number) < number)
{
    number += 0.5m;
}
return decimal.Round(number) / multiplier;
}
```

Taken from: [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default?rq=1)

This question also asks why .Net uses bankers rounding. So I believe it will be a good read for you.

*To answer why*

This bankers algorithm means that results collected will be evenly spread of rounding up/down when the decimal == .5, so really it is just to even out data results.

Here's another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775795/c-sharp-bankers-rounding-error?rq=1) which describes this by Mr. Skeet

Comment: Look at these input values: For x = 0.002 I get rounded: 0.010 (xml rounds to 0.000) using the above function ...

Answer (score 3):

[Math.Floor(double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=vs.90).aspx) seems to be supported, so;

```
private static double RoundToTwo(double value)
{
    return Math.Floor(100*value + .5)/100;
}

Console.WriteLine(RoundToTwo(1.165));
> 1.17

Console.WriteLine(RoundToTwo(1.16499));
> 1.16
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    double number = 1.165;
    string RoundedNumber = number.ToString("f3");
```

Where 3 is the scale